# Dafault Values into mysql table

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on a php site with uses mysql as database, now my site is a social network like site where users follow each other, now if a user joins in he is following nobody so his stream remains empty so they leave the site quickly as well,i want users to be following my account account automatically when he joins in. Can you please tell me how to do it

here are the two tables

Table structure for table `sn_users`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sn_users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
`picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cover` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`job` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` int(11) NOT NULL,
`reg_id` text,
`active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table structure for table `sn_follows`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sn_follows` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`from` int(11) NOT NULL,
`to` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the php code is

```
public function userRegister($array)
{
$username = $this->__GB->__DB->escape_string($array['username']);
$email = $this->__GB->__DB->escape_string($array['email']);
$password = md5($array['password']);
if (strlen(trim($username)) <= 4) {
$response = array(
'done' => false,
'message' => 'Username too short'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
} else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
$response = array(
'done' => false,
'message' => 'Invalid E-mail'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
} else if (strlen(trim($array['password'])) <= 5) {
$response = array(
'done' => false,
'message' => 'Password too short'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
} else if ($this->UserExist($username)) {
$response = array(
'done' => false,
'message' => 'Username already exists'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
} else {
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
$imageID = $this->__GB->uploadImage($_FILES['image']);
} else {
$imageID = null;
}
$array = array(
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'email' => $email,
'date' => time(),
'picture' => $imageID
);
if ($this->__GB->GetConfig('emailactivation', 'users') == 1) {
$array['active'] = 0;
}
$insert = $this->__GB->__DB->insert('users', $array);
if ($insert) {
if ($this->__GB->GetConfig('emailactivation', 'users') == 1) {
$this->sendEmailActivation($this->__GB->__DB->lastID(), $email);
}
$response = array(
'done' => true,
'message' => 'Your account has been created'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
} else {
$response = array(
'done' => false,
'message' => 'Oops Something Went Wrong'
);
$this->__GB->prepareMessage($response);
}
}


}
```

Comment: When you create a new user, explicitly add the "account" as something being followed.  This has nothing to do with the database.  Just do what you want in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MYSQL trigger for that action. As soon as the user registers for the social network, the SQL trigger will create a sn_follows record that puts you as their first person following.

[MYSQL Trigger documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Good luck